# Given $a, b,c,d$ non-negative and $a+b+c+d=4$. Prove that $a^3b+b^3c+c^3d+d^3a+23abcd \le 27.$

Tags: inequality

> This is a problem on Mathlinks.ro and it have had no solution. So I hope it would have a nice answer and as simply as possible.
>
> Given $a, b,c,d$ are non-negative numbers and $a+b+c+d=4$. Prove that $$a^3b+b^3c+c^3d+d^3a+23abcd \le 27.$$

Comment: Are a,b,c,d integers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can trade off the cyclic symmetry to reduce the number of variables to consider.  The homogeneous form is:
$$4^4(a^3b+b^3c+c^3d+d^3a+23abcd) \le 27(a+b+c+d)^4$$

WLOG, let $a$ be the minimum among $a, b, c, d$; and so we have non-negatives $x, y, z$ s.t. $b = a+x, \, c = a+y, \, d = a+z$.  Hence we get an inequality of form
$$f(x, y, z)\cdot a^2+g(x, y, z)\cdot a+h(x, y, z) \ge 0$$

It is easy to check $f = 32\cdot23[(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2] + 32\cdot11(x^2+y^2+z^2) \ge 0$

$g = 16 (11x^3 + 33x^2y + 81x^2z + 81xy^2 - 206xyz + 81xz^2 + 11y^3 + 33y^2z + 81yz^2 + 11z^3)$ which is non-negative as AM-GM gives:
$$11x^3 + 33x^2y + 81x^2z + 81xy^2 + 81xz^2 + 11y^3 + 33y^2z + 81yz^2 + 11z^3 \\ \ge 9\cdot9\cdot11^{5/9} \cdot xyz \ge 9\cdot9\cdot3\cdot xyz \ge 206xyz$$

It only remains to show $h \ge 0$, which is the same as setting one variable to zero, or showing $4^4(a^3b+b^3c) \le 27(a+b+c)^4$.

In fact it is not hard to prove the stronger cyclic version $4^4(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a) \le 27(a+b+c)^4$ or the tougher version $a+b+c=4 \implies a^3b+b^3c+c^3a+\frac{473}{64}abc \le 27$ using exactly the same technique to reduce variables from $3 \to 2$!

Answer (score 2):

Given the problem, we use

> $$
> \begin{eqnarray}
> a &=& u^2\\
> b &=& v^2\\
> c &=& w^2\\
> d &=& x^2
> \end{eqnarray} \tag 1
> $$

So the boundary condition is given by

> $$
> u^2 + v^2 + w^2 + x^2 = 4, \tag 2
> $$

for any $u$, $v$, $w$ and $x$.

We define

> $$
> S(u,v,w,x) = u^6 v^2 + v^6 w^2 + w^6 x^2 + x^6 u^2 + 23 u^2 v^2 w^2 x^2.
> \tag 3
> $$

Whence

> $$
> \begin{eqnarray}
> \frac{\partial S}{\partial u} &=& 6 u^5 v^2 + 2 x^6 u + 46 u v^2 w^2 x^2,\\
> \frac{\partial S}{\partial v} &=& 6 v^5 w^2 + 2 u^6 v + 46 u^2 v w^2 x^2,\\
> \frac{\partial S}{\partial w} &=& 6 w^5 x^2 + 2 v^6 w + 46 u^2 v^2 w x^2,\\
> \frac{\partial S}{\partial x} &=& 6 x^5 u^2 + 2 w^6 x + 46 u^2 v^2 w^2 x.\\
> \end{eqnarray} \tag 4
> $$

---

We know that

> $$
> u = v = w = x = 1 \tag 5
> $$

satisfies the boundary condition and we obtain

> $$
> \frac{\partial S}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial v}
> = \frac{\partial S}{\partial w} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial x} = 54. \tag 6
> $$

But as

> $$
> dx = - du - dv - dw, \tag 7
> $$

we obtain

> $$
> d S = \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial u}
>     - \frac{\partial S}{\partial x} \right) d u
>     + \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial v}
>     - \frac{\partial S}{\partial x} \right) d v
>     + \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial w}
>     - \frac{\partial S}{\partial x} \right) d w = 0. \tag 8
> $$

So the "point" $(1,1,1,1)$ is an extreme value for $S$, and that value is $27$.

---

Another extreme "point " is $(0,0,0,2)$, and we obtain

> $$
> S(0,0,0,2) = 0 \tag 9
> $$

So the extreme "point" $(1,1,1,1)$ is a maximum, whence

> $$
> u^6 v^2 + v^6 w^2 + w^6 x^2 + x^6 u^2 + 23 u^2 v^2 w^2 x^2 \le 27 \tag {10}
> $$

Or going back to $(a,b,c,d)$, we get

> $$
> \bbox[16px,border:2px solid #800000] {
>    a^3 b + b^3 c + c^3 d + d^3 a + 23 a b c d \le 27. } \tag {11}
> $$

Comment: The challenge usually is in finding **all** extreme points and then ensuring we have the global maximum.  Plugging in a few smart guesses is the easy part. Here you missed $(u, v, w, x) \sim (\sqrt3, 1, 0, 0)$.

Comment: You are correct Macavity. I do not have the time right now to make a correction.